# What is the best diction for 'screaming loudly but in happy condition'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

My best diction attempt is "**screeching jovially**". But I'm not sure if **screech** collocates with **jovial**.

My reason to choose this diction is where I found **screech = loud cry**. In this case, cry means making a loud sound not shedding tears. Again I'm not really sure if this is correct since some examples I've seen **screech** is used to describe unpleasant sound for instance 'He screeched with pain'. What do you think about 'screeching jovially'? Does it make sense?

Comment: **screech** is unequivocally negative, or at the very least neutral (when describing the cry of a bird).

Comment: I suppose you could say "screeching joyfully", but it is notable for being unusual.  "Screaming with joy" or "screaming joyfully" is more natural.  I am not sure that *jovial* is the word you want; it means something more like "friendly" than "happy".

Comment: "Shouting" might work better than "screeching", although "shouting" usually implies words are being used.  "Screaming" is better than "screeching" if joy is involved. "Shrieking" or "squealing" could work.